# Spring xslt processing works on a string but not a dom

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel 2.10.4 to create xml documents. I want to view the xml as html in one use case so my Camel route (defined in Spring DSL) uses an xslt to transform the xml document to html.

The xml is generated in a Java bean and output as a DOM Document.

If I use convertBodyTo to convert the Document to a String before handing it to the xslt all is well. If I leave this out, the xslt processor doesn't find the elements in my document.

This returns an html string with a table containing a row for each schedule item in my TVAnytime xml document:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:show_bn"/>
  <to uri="bean:gen"/>
  <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
  <to uri="xslt:tva2html.xslt"/>
  <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
    <constant>text/html;</constant>
  </setHeader>
</route>
```

This returns the html with no rows in the table:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:show_bn"/>
  <to uri="bean:gen"/>
  <to uri="xslt:tva2html.xslt"/>
  <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
    <constant>text/html;</constant>
  </setHeader>
</route>
```

The method executed in the bean has this signature:

```
public org.w3c.dom.Document process();
```

Any idea why this is happening? I suspect something wrong with namespace aware processing when the xslt processing gets a DOM.

Answer (score 1):

I just added [a quick test](http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/diff/01b3cc09) in camel-core, I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks Willem, your test doesn't check that the transformation happened. I will add some more detail to the question.